# Looping CSV Into URL

Tags: python, csv

I need to download a ton (thousands) of PDF files for work. The PDF files all download from the same URL (sample below) with the only change being the number that follows `objId=` part. This seems like a perfect opportunity to "automate the boring stuff" and amaze my boss, but my program fails because the output into the URL gives a [%27...%27] on both ends of the objId, which isn't the address I want to open.

Desired URL (redacted): `https://.../cs.exe?func=ll&objId=385135288&objAction=download`

I have a csv file that lists all of the objId numbers. That csv looks like:

`385135288
385030780
385156245
385283431
384988131`

Here is my Python code:

```
import csv
import webbrowser
f = open('5_Sample_Object_IDs.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    obj_id = row
    url = 'https://.../cs.exe?func=ll&objId='+str(obj_id)+'&objAction=download'
    webbrowser.open(url)
print('Complete! Check your Downloads folder.')
```

And my output is:

```
['385135288']
['385030780']
['385156245']
['385283431']
['384988131']
```

Output URL: `https://.../cs.exe?func=ll&objId=[%27384988131%27]&objAction=download`

It seems that my issue comes from the ['...'] with each output; the URL is taking the `[` and converting the `'` into `%27`. I can't figure out how to get around this. How could I get this program to just output the digits?

Many thanks for any help or guideance!

Comment: It seems that `row` is a `list`.  If your data is in a consistent format you should be able to get away with just doing `obj_id = row[0]` to pull the first (and in this case, only) element out of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to use the CSV reader here. You just have a list of URLs, you should read them directly.

```
f = open('5_Sample_Object_IDs.csv')
for row in f:
    obj_id = row.strip()
    url = 'https://.../cs.exe?func=ll&objId='+str(obj_id)+'&objAction=download'
```

Comment: This is perfect. Daniel, thank you so much! It worked exactly as I wanted. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Looks like you just need to reference the index of the list the `obj_id` is in:

```
obj_id = row[0]
```

You are passing the list to your `str()` instead of the string element in the list. Then you can also omit the `str()` call. I also would recommend using  `.format()` instead of concatenating strings:

```
import csv
import webbrowser
f = open('5_Sample_Object_IDs.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    obj_id = row[0]
    url = 'https://.../cs.exe?func=ll&objId={}&objAction=download'.format(obj_id)
    webbrowser.open(url)
print('Complete! Check your Downloads folder.')
```